# jQuery a better idea to add active class to menu item

Tags: jquery, url, menu

This simple script adds an "active" class to a link in a list when page's url is = link's href attribute

```
var TheP   = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var HeRe   = TheP[TheP.length-1];
$('ul a').each(function(){
 var Link  = $(this).attr('href');
      if (Link == HeRe){ $(this).addClass('active');}
 });
```

And it works. But ... only when the **href** attribute is just a single file  `href="index.html"`. Doesn't work at all in these next cases or similar:

```
<a href="foo/index.html">foo</a>
<a href="../bar/index.html">bar</a>
```

Actually to solve it I could write:

```
 var TheP = window.location.pathname.split('/');
 var P1   = TheP[TheP.length-1];
 var P2   = TheP[TheP.length-2];
 var HeRe = P2+"/"+P1;

 $('ul a').each(function(){
  var Ln = $(this).attr('href');
  var Ln = Ln.split('/');
  var L1 = Ln[Ln.length-1];
  var L2 = Ln[Ln.length-2];
  var Link = L2+"/"+L1;
      if (Link == HeRe){$(this).addClass('active');}
 });
```

But ... ehm ... I think there should be a better and more flexible way. Also because what is above doesn't work having just a single file as path : (

Comment: @user: Updated my answer, I misunderstood the question at first (although it's actually fairly clearly written).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: I misunderstood the question originally. Re-reading it, it sounds like you want to be sure *not* to match all `index.html`s, but only the specific one you're in (which makes rather more sense, actually).

In that case, you can do this:

```
var path = window.location.href; // Just grabbing a handy reference to it
$('ul a').each(function() {
    if (this.href === path) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

...because the `href` property (which is *not* the same as the "href" attribute) of the DOM element [is the absolute path](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-88517319).

**[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uboge5/2)**

Obviously, the more you can do to constrain that initial selector (within reason), the better. For instance, if this is all within some navigation structure, only working within that structure will be more efficient.

Also, if there will be a *lot* of matches, you can avoid doing the jQuery wrapper when adding the class if you like:

```
    if (this.href === path) {
        this.className += " active"; // note the space
    }
```

---

**Original answer**:

If the `href` attributes will always have a `/` before the filename part, then:

```
var TheP   = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var HeRe   = TheP[TheP.length-1];
$('ul a[href$="/' + HeRe + '"]').addClass('active');
```

That uses an [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to find the relevant links.

If the `href` attributes may sometimes be simply `index.html` or similar, you can do this:

```
var TheP   = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var HeRe   = TheP[TheP.length-1];
$('ul a[href$="/' + HeRe + '"], ul a[href="' + HeRe + '"]').addClass('active');
```

...which will catch the ones with `/` in front of them using the "ends-with" selector, and also the ones where there's an exact match using the "equals" selector.

Comment: J. ... thanks and sorry for my english, I've seen your kind Live example and yes it works. But it's not useful if you have hrefs like these: href="**../A/index.html**" or href="**../B/index.html**" and so on. Because my two scripts work, but they work separately. I would like ONLY ONE script instead, to match the correct hrefs having a menu with "index.html" and "foo.html" or "../A/index.html" and "../B/index.html" or even "../A/B/index.html" and "../B/B/index.html" where the relevant parts could be different.

Comment: @user: (Your English seems fine.) I'm not sure I understand, the reason I'm using the `href` property instead of the "href" attribute is that it *won't* be relative. By the time the DOM is parsed, if you have a `<a href="../A/index.html">` in a page at `http://example.com/foo/B/nifty.html`, the `href` *property* on the DOM element for that anchor will be `http://example.com/foo/A/index.html`. The *property* is a fully-resolved absolute path. Since we compare that with `window.location.href`, which is also an absolute path, we can use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than break up the pathname why don't you just compare the whole thing. If you have relative urls it should be easy. Also, you can perform a replace to deal with absolute urls.

```
var mainpart = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
var path = '/' + window.location.pathname;
$('ul a').each(function(){
    var Link  = $(this).attr('href').replace(mainpart, '');
    if (Link === path || '/' + Link === path){ $(this).addClass('active');}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I need :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var TheP = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var HeRe = TheP[TheP.length-1];
$('ul a[href$="' + HeRe + '"]').addClass('active');
```

According to specification http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings :

Three additional attribute selectors are provided for matching substrings in the value of an attribute:

- **[att^=val]** Represents an element with
  the att attribute whose value begins
  with the prefix "val". If "val" is
  the empty string then the selector
  does not represent anything.
- **[att$=val]** Represents an element with
  the att attribute whose value ends
  with the suffix "val". If "val" is
  the empty string then the selector
  does not represent anything.
- **[att*=val]** Represents an element with
  the att attribute whose value
  contains at least one instance of the
  substring "val". If "val" is the
  empty string then the selector does
  not represent anything.

Comment: .. interesting approach the CSS3 selectors. But using **[href*= ]** or **[href$= ]** you would get too many matches. Think the menu scenario with an href="../A/index.html" or href="../B/index.html"